# Compare columns in Linux

Tags: shell-script, awk

I would like to compare column 3 of File1 vs column 2 of File2. If any value of column 3 of File1 is not present in column 2 of File2, print that full line of File1.

File1:

```
5/3/2021        Mobile   $2,627.59
5/3/2021        Phone    $2,056.11
5/3/2021        Loan     $5,146.11
```

File2:

```
5/11/2021   $2,627.59 
5/12/2021   $2,056.11
5/15/2021   $7,516.11
5/13/2021   $406.11
5/12/2021   $2,056.11
```

Desired output:

```
5/3/2021        Loan     $5,146.11
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to indicate what you already tried and where you ran into problem. That way contributors can understand what tools you have available/are familiar with, and you can avoid receiving proposed solutions that you already know won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{ values[$2]; next }
  !($3 in values)
' File2 File1
```

This reads `File2` first and saves the second field in array `values` as index. The test `NR==FNR` is only true for the first non-empty input file. The script continues with the `next` record to skip the next line of code.

Then `File1` is read and it is checked if the 3rd field is not present as index in the `values` array.
If true, it prints the current record (the default action).

Answer (score 1):

Using a shell with process substitutions (sort the files first separately if you have a shell without `<(...)`):

```bsh
join -v 1 -1 3 -2 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3 \
    <( sort -b -k 3,3 File1 ) \
    <( sort -b -k 2,2 File2 )
```

This performs a relational JOIN operation between the two sorted data sets, using the 3rd column of the first set (`-1 3`) and the 2nd column of the other set (`-2 2`) as the join fields.  The output from `join` will be the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd column from the first file, as specified by the `-o` option.  Only the lines from the first file that can't be joined to any line in the second file will be outputted (`-v 1`).

The input to `join` has to be sorted using `sort -b` on the column that will be used as the join field, which is what the two process substitutions do.

The output from this using the given data will be

```
5/3/2021 Loan $5,146.11
```

If your files use tabs as field delimiters, you may want to use

```bsh
join -t $'\t' -v 1 -1 3 -2 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3 \
    <( sort -t $'\t' -b -k 3,3 File1 ) \
    <( sort -t $'\t' -b -k 2,2 File2 )
```